# Query built with Criteria API doesn't return any results, manually executing it does

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, eclipselink, criteria-api

This is part of the java code that builds the Criteria API expression:

```
        Expression<Boolean> fun = cb.function("jsonb_contains",
                Boolean.class, r.get(MediaEntity_.metadataItems),
                cb.function("to_jsonb", Object.class, cb.literal("[{\"key\":\"supplierProductId\", \"value\":\"123-123-12348\"}]"))
        );
```

Eclipselink logger outputs following query and parameters:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID AS a1, created_at AS a2, data_hash AS a3, DELETED AS a4, 
metadata_items AS a5, NAME AS a6, relative_path AS a7, TYPE AS a8, updated_at AS 
a9, VERSION AS a10 FROM media  
WHERE (jsonb_contains(metadata_items, to_jsonb(?)) = ?) 
LIMIT ? OFFSET ?

bind => [[{"key":"supplierProductId", "value":"123-123-12348"}], true, 20, 0]
```

Query looks ok, but I'm getting no hits.
If I manually execute similar query with same parameters I get the result:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID AS a1, created_at AS a2, data_hash AS a3, DELETED AS a4, metadata_items AS a5, NAME AS a6, relative_path AS a7, TYPE AS a8, updated_at AS a9, VERSION AS a10 FROM media
WHERE
(jsonb_contains(metadata_items, '[{"key":"supplierProductId", "value":"123-123-12348"}]') = true)
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

Note that I didn't need to use `to_jsonb` in manual query, but had to add it in Criteria API - is this what is causing the problem?

Comment: You should test the exact same query, otherwise the results might be off. One difference I can see is the EclipseLink query using `to_jsonb(?)` while your manual query directly passes the string.

Comment: Yes, this is true. I tried to use exact same query but couldn't because of the following:

1. If I don't use `to_jsonb` in Eclipselink query, I get an error: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function jsonb_contains(jsonb, character varying) does not exist

2. If I use `to_jsonb` in manual query I get an error:
 ERROR: could not determine polymorphic type because input has type unknown

Comment: Try something like `to_jsonb('json'::text)` make the parameter a text (or if possible try `varchar`)

Comment: Tried it with `to_jsonb('json'::text)` and also getting no results now manually. Could the problem be character escapes:
`SELECT * FROM "to_jsonb"('[{"key":"supplierProductId", "value":"123-123-12348"}}]'::text);` -> `"[{\"key\":\"supplierProductId\", \"value\":\"123-123-12348\"}}]"` ?

Comment: Those escapes shouldn't be present in the string passed to `to_jsonb` as this is Java only.

Comment: Escapes are result of call to `to_jsonb` (this is what `SELECT * FROM "to_jsonb"....` outputs)

Comment: Hmm, I'd expect `select * from to_jsonb('some json'::text)` to output proper json. Could you try with `cast(? as json)` instead? Or maybe use the built-in operators like `?|`. It's been a while since I was working on a problem like this and unfortunately I don't have access to the code anymore and need to rely on my memory.

Comment: Yes, that works (manual query). How to use the cast with Criteria API though?
I think I am going to try to build query like this in Criteria API: `SELECT * FROM "json_build_array"(json_build_object('key', 'supplierProductId', 'value', '123-123-12348'));`

Comment: That's a good question. If I remember correctly I used JPQL back then which allowed me to add the `cast( ? as json)` directly (or something like that) but I'm not quite sure how Criteria Query would do it. You could always add a small function around this :)

Comment: I managed to do it like this (output from Eclipselink): `SELECT DISTINCT ID AS a1, created_at AS a2, data_hash AS a3, DELETED AS a4, metadata_items AS a5, NAME AS a6, relative_path AS a7, TYPE AS a8, updated_at AS a9, VERSION AS a10 FROM media WHERE (jsonb_contains(metadata_items, jsonb_build_array(json_build_object(?, ?), json_build_object(?, ?))) = ?) LIMIT ? OFFSET ?
 bind => [key, supplierProductId, value, 123-123-12348, true, 20, 0]`